Commutative Banach $\mathbb{R}$-algebras without complex structure, but with path-connected group of units
For a finite-dimensional commutative (associative, unital) $\mathbb{R}$-algebra $A$, the condition $\pi_0(A^\times) = 1$ (i.e. the group of units of $A$ being path-connected) is equivalent to $A$ having a compatible complex structure, i.e. having $a \in A$ with $a^2 = -1$. The standard arguments for this break in infinite dimensions.

Are there examples of infinite-dimensional commutative Banach $\mathbb{R}$-algebras $A$ with $\pi_0(A^\times)=1$, but without compatible complex structure?


@YCor: everything is assumed commutative.

Is this 1990 paper by Pfafferberger and Phillips relevant? it obtains a Gelfand-like representation for commutative real algebras, and §4 (p18) discusses the difference between complex and almost complex.

@YCor: thanks, yes, this paper appears relevant. The condition $\pi_0(A^\times)=1$ forces $A$ to be "almost complex" in their terminology, so Thm. 4.8 would suggest to try and find a suitable example that is almost complex, but not complex. In particular, Example 5.2 (ii) seemed like a good candidate: it's easy to see by differentiation that the algebra there has no $f$ with $f^2 = -1$, but I haven't been able to construct a path between two $f_0,f_1 \in A^\times$, even though intuitively there should be one (these are just loops in $\mathbb{C}$ away from $0$ exhibiting certain symmetry).

Actually, strike what I previously said, it's not clear at all that there should be path, since it's only an $\mathbb{R}$-algebra and it seems that such a path should produce an 'intermediate' loop that goes around $0$, and hence also some loop inbetween that must cross 0. One could probably actually show this using topological index, so my previous intuition seems way off.

There exists a separable Banach space $X$ with a Schauder basis such that the algebra $D(X)$ of the diagonal operators consists of operators $ Τ = \lambda I + K $ where K is a compact operator https://arxiv.org/abs/0902.1646 . This seems to me relevant to the question.

@SArgyros: thanks, could you elaborate a little bit on this? I am not a functional analyst (pun not intended).
